# Creating multiple process and simulation in C via fork()

Tags: c, unix

i want to create multiple process groups which will call different functions.

i write the code below.
firstly i want to get following output

./fork 4 5

```
 I am a child: 1 PID: 22330
 I am a child2: 1 PID: 22334
 I am a child: 2 PID: 22331
 I am a child2: 5 PID: 22338
 I am a child: 4 PID: 22333
 I am a child: 3 PID: 22332
 I am a child2: 2 PID: 22335
 I am a child2: 4 PID: 22337
 I am a child2: 3 PID: 22336
```

'

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

void forkChildren (int nChildren) {
     int i;
     pid_t pid;
     for (i = 1; i <= nChildren; i++) {
        pid = fork();
        if (pid == -1) {
          /* error handling here, if needed */
        return;
        }
        if (pid == 0) {
           printf("I am a child: %d PID: %d\n",i, getpid());
           sleep (5);
        wait(NULL);
        return;
        }
     }
  }
 void forkChildren2 (int nChildren) {
      int i;
      pid_t pid;
      for (i = 1; i <= nChildren; i++) {
          pid = fork();
          if (pid == -1) {
            /* error handling here, if needed */
          return;
          }
          if (pid == 0) {
             printf("I am a child2: %d PID: %d\n",i, getpid());
             sleep (2);
             return;
          }
       }
   }

   int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {

      forkChildren (atoi (argv[1]));
      forkChildren2 (atoi (argv[2]));

     return 0;
  }
```

the code gives me the output

```
[ozdeny@hyperion ~]$ ./fork 4 5
I am a child: 1 PID: 22330
I am a child: 2 PID: 22331 
I am a child: 3 PID: 22332 
I am a child: 4 PID: 22333
I am a child2: 1 PID: 22334 
I am a child2: 2 PID: 22335
I am a child2: 4 PID: 22337 
I am a child2: 5 PID: 22338
[ozdeny@hyperion ~]$ I am a child2: 3 PID: 22336
I am a child2: 1 PID: 22339
I am a child2: 2 PID: 22340
I am a child2: 3 PID: 22341
I am a child2: 4 PID: 22342 
I am a child2: 5 PID: 22343
I am a child2: 1 PID: 22345
I am a child2: 2 PID: 22346
I am a child2: 3 PID: 22347
I am a child2: 1 PID: 22349
I am a child2: 2 PID: 22350
I am a child2: 1 PID: 22344
I am a child2: 2 PID: 22352
I am a child2: 3 PID: 22353
I am a child2: 4 PID: 22354
I am a child2: 5 PID: 22355
I am a child2: 3 PID: 22351
I am a child2: 4 PID: 22356
I am a child2: 5 PID: 22357
I am a child2: 4 PID: 22348
I am a child2: 5 PID: 22358
```

Comment: does fflush(stdout) make things print more orderly?

Comment: Still trying to understand what's the question here.

Comment: Some details are missing from your "question", like the main code and what is the problem about.

Comment: sorry i added the missing code

Comment: Please, update your question to mention the problem you described in the comment below.

Comment: Add a `while (wait(0) > 0) ;` loop in the main() so that the parent waits for its children to die before exiting itself.

Answer (score 2):

```
[ozdeny@hyperion ~]$ I am a child2: 3 PID: 22336
```

If this is your problem this means that your root process exits earlier than it's child processes. Make the root wait for it's children processes with a waitpid()[1].

[1] http://linux.die.net/man/2/waitpid

**LE:** You put waitpid in the root process not the forked process.

**LLE:** Ok i finally got what you want to do and an idea came from jweyrich observation, it goes like so return the array of pids for its child processes and then terminate them from the root process.

The main should look like this:

```
int* child_pids
//mem allocation
forkChildren();
for each pid in child_pids
  kill(pid,*signal termination*)
forkChildren2()
```

Comment: i'm confused.Where will i put the wait()

Comment: fork() will be called twice where is the root process.
i want to get 4 child and 5 child2 it gives me 20 child2

Comment: That's because all `child` are returning from `forkChildren` and running `forkChildren2`. So you get 4 * 5 = 20. You have to change the way you fork, or put a condition to run `forkChildren2` only in the parent process.

Answer (score 2):

According to a comment you made at @Cristina's answer, the problem is that it's forking 20 child2 instead of only 5, as specified on the command-line argument. The cause is that each child process created by `forkChildren` is returning to `main` and calling `forkChildren2`. You get 20 (in fact 25) child2 because 4 (forkChildren) * 5 (forkChildren2) = 20, plus the 5  created by the parent process.

I added return values to the functions (to both, just to keep them similar), and a `if` condition to skip `forkChildren2` if it's a child process.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int forkChildren(int nChildren) {
    int i;
    pid_t pid;
    for (i = 1; i <= nChildren; i++) {
        pid = fork();
        if (pid == -1) {
            /* error handling here, if needed */
            return -1;
        }
        if (pid == 0) {
            printf("I am a child: %d PID: %d\n",i, getpid());
            sleep(5);
            return 1;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

int forkChildren2(int nChildren) {
    int i;
    pid_t pid;
    for (i = 1; i <= nChildren; i++) {
        pid = fork();
        if (pid == -1) {
            /* error handling here, if needed */
            return -1;
        }
        if (pid == 0) {
            printf("I am a child2: %d PID: %d\n", i, getpid());
            sleep(2);
            return 1;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    int ret;
    if (argc != 3) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s <nChild> <nChild2>\n", getprogname());
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    ret = forkChildren(atoi(argv[1]));
    if (ret == 0)
        forkChildren2(atoi(argv[2]));
    // wait(...) for all pids here, if you wish
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: thanks for help.It works correcttly.What if i wan't to simulate childs.Let them work different order.sleep function  can't do it. should i try using semaphores

Comment: What do you mean by _work in different order_? Thread are independent of each other. Semaphores are used for synchronisation. I might be able to help if you give a good description of what you want to do.

Comment: in fact,i'm trying to write multiple producer single consumer simulation.

in forkChildren add_a() will called 
in forkChildren2 cosume_a will called.

if i put this functions firsty add_a wfunction called by number of children of first fork.

and then consume_a() function called by number of children of second fork.i want to simulate like example.(it may work different order)

add_a()
consume_()
add_a()
add_a()
consume_a()

Comment: Thanks, now I understand. You don't need to worry about the order they'll be executed, but you need semaphores to signal the consumer threads that one item is available on the queue/list/whatever. Whenever the producer puts a item in the container, it signals the consumers to wakeup, and process the item. Doing this, you avoid processor-consuming loops. For more informations, read http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Producer-consumer_problem